# Rank of Principal submatrix of annihilator matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, linear-regression, projection-matrices

In the classic linear regression setting,

$y = X\beta+\epsilon$, where $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^p$, and $\epsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2I)$.

$P = X(X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top$ is called the projection matrix or hat matrix.

$M = I-P$ is called the annihilator matrix.

We know if $rank(X) = p$, then $rank(P) = p$ and $rank(M) = n-p$.

Suppose $X$ indeed has full column rank. In particular, let's assume that the rows of X are in general positions, i.e. any p rows of X are linearly independent.

I want to find an upper bound $S$, s.t. for any $s\leq S$, any $s\times s$ principal submatrix of M is invertible.

A few useful properties:

1. $M$ eigen spectrum contains p zeros and n-p ones.
2. $P$ is a projection matrix in the sense that $P^2=P$. Similarly, $M^2=M$.

Any hints are helpful.

Comment: The term is *principal* submatrix.  "Principal" means primary or main. A "principle" is a concept or idea.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are matrices $X$ (with full rank) such that for *any* $s \geq 1$, there is a non-invertible $s \times s$ submatrix.  For instance:
$$
X = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0} \implies M = \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}
$$
Note that any principal submatrix which includes the first row/column will fail to be invertible.

Comment: In case I misunderstood your question: it might be useful to note that a matrix has rank $r$ if and only if it has an invertible $s \times s$ submatrix.

Comment: thanks again. The counter example here is kind of special, in the sense that X has all-zero rows. A follow up question: What if X doesn't contain any all-zero rows, and, in particular, let's assume the rows of X are in general positions.

Comment: I would suspect that your condition holds for $S = n - p$ "with probability $1$".  In fact, I suspect there's a neat argument that this is the case by considering the principal subdeterminants as polynomials.  Such arguments are very common in the field of algebraic geometry.